# Foul play in Pell’s equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Pells equation $x^2-dy^2=1$   has the obvious x and y solutions $x=n$, $y=1$ for $d=n^2-1$. The next and higher solution for the same d is $x=2n^2-1$ and $y=2n$.
This offers a method for calculation of higher solutions via Brahmagupta’s rule (as in Wikipedia under the heading Pell’s equation). I then calculate these higher solutions by simply using an excel sheet starting with an entry n and via $d=n^2-1$. I calculate a series of higher solutions for $d=n^2-1$.

I now proceed to do something partly odd or illegal: I simply enter $n=\sqrt n$ instead of $n$. This gives me $d=n-1$, and I now insert $n=\sqrt{62}$ to receive $d=61$ and wondered of I might get integers for both $x$ and $y$ when the “right” numbers came up ($1\, 766\, \,319\, 049$ and $226\, 153\, 980$ for $x$ and $y$ respectively). However in my $5$th solution i.e. my third Brahmagupta iteration I get the numbers $z= 1\, 830\, 972\, 097$ and $y= 234\, 431\, 954.54$.

Surprisingly these numbers are not far from the real solutions for $d=61$ and they are off both by the same amount, only $3.660$ %.

Could this be just a coincidence?

Comment: This might suggest some sort of "well-posedness" of Pellian equations? Interesting...

Comment: To be clearer:  The two first solutions combined by Brahmagupta’s rule give the 3rd, No 2 and 3 give the 4th and No 3 and 4 give the 5th. Also my new y using $sqrt(62)$ ends with ..954.54.. i.e. it is it not an integer. (By mistake I used the Swedish comma i lieu of ".")

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the small difference is just a coincidence. If you try the same with some other numbers (such as $d=337$), you'll see find the results of the Brahmagupta iteration starting from non-integer pairs to be considerably different from the "exact" solution.

Of course, the fact that both numbers are off by the same *relative* amount is trivial since the ratio of $x$ and $y$ must be almost exactly equal to $\sqrt{d}$ (and it gets closer and closer with growing $x$) both for the "exact" and for the "approximate" pairs.

Comment: I am aware that the method does not work for all cases of d or even for all primes or all primes of the type $d=n(n+1)(n+2)+1$ such as the one you mention, $ d=337=6*7*8+1$.  However if you choose (and perhaps you did) the nearest higher example after 61 namely $d=221=5*6*7+1$ you find that the two numbers were within 9% (2,78E+11 vs 2,56E+11) for the same third Brahmagupta iteration.  This is close in an environment where the numbers differ one or several factors of 1000 in every step. I tried and failed in a similar way with other “61 families” such as $n^2-3$ or$ 2^n-3$.